# Factory Method pattern vs ordinary abstract class implementation

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'm trying to understand the Factory Method pattern. I've managed to distinguish it from the *Simple Factory*, but now I don't get why it's actually called a "pattern". Please, look at my example below:

**Class Diagram link**

[image]

Sample java code for **Messenger**:

```
public String exchangeMessages(String messageToSend) {
   Socket socket = getSocket();
   socket.open();
   socket.send(messageToSend);
   String receivedMessage = socket.receive();
   socket.close();
   return receivedMessage;
}
```

And for **Client**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Messenger messenger = new TCPMessenger("127.0.0.1", 4321);
   String result = messenger.exchangeMessages("Hello!");
   System.out.println(result);
}
```

If I understand correctly, everything makes sense because `exchangeMessages` method exists. We use the abstract *factory method* `getSocket` inside it and thanks to it we:

> let subclasses decide which class to instantiate

But isn't it just an ordinary abstract class implementation? We take advantage of the code shared by both `TCPMessenger` and `UDPMessenger` - for me, this is not a pattern but a core feature of Object-Oriented Programming that everybody knows from the beggining of OOP language learning!

Moreover, I think that naming this **creational** is very confusing. We actually care about `exchangeMessages` method, so `Client` (part of the code that uses our "pattern") is not even aware of the `Socket` class which creation we're all about. It's more like a way to implement `Messenger` functionallity (which can be easily extended etc...) than a way to really create something.

Am I missing the point or is my example invalid? Please guys, let me know what do you thing about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: GOF Design patterns are Collection of Best practices. The above example demonstrates Factory method design pattern. The strength of this pattern is that _Abstract Creators can publish application specific logic only in terms of Abstract Product_ in absence of concrete creators and concrete Products (which clients are free to write as per requirements). This is very much helpful in writing frameworks where logic is defined before involved concrete classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Factory Method pattern is a simple pattern, but still a pattern nonetheless.

**Your `Client` and its relationship to the Factory Method**

The Gang of Four (GoF) definition of the Factory Method Pattern does not specifically mention a `Client` as a participant of the pattern itself. In reality the `Client` is most likely to use the Factory Method indirectly through some other operation.

In your case as the `Client` does not care about the `Socket` being used, but just the `Messenger` itself. However, the `Messenger` is dependent upon a `Socket` as it has some behavior that uses a `Socket` Object.

So whilst the `Client` itself does not care about the `Socket`, it does care about the `Messenger` which has a *use* dependency with `Socket`.

As the `Socket` itself is abstract it gives us a problem, as we don't want to replicate the same logic in `exchangeMessages(String)` multiple times for the different implementations of `Socket` (`TCPSocket` and `UDPSocket`), especially when we may want to add more `Socket` classes at a later date.

This is where the *Factory Method pattern* comes into play, as we can define all the generalized behavior for exchanging messages at an abstract level, but leave the *creation* of the actual `Socket` implementation (`TCPSocket` and `UDPSocket`) to subclasses of `Messenger` (`TCPMessenger` and `UDPMessenger`).

---

**Discussion of alternatives to the Factory Method Pattern**

You could just set the `Socket` as a field of `Messenger`, and inject it using a *Strategy pattern* approach or have a constructor that takes a `Socket` as a parameter. A drawback of this approach is that we'll have to maintain a reference to this `Socket` Object as a class field in anticipation of it's use.

However, with the Factory Method Pattern, the `Socket` will only be created in the method `exchangeMessages()` when needed and then discarded when the method terminates, which may be of some benefit. This comes at the cost of having to create one of the `Socket` Objects each time `exchangeMessages()` is called, which may not be ideal.

You could also pass the required `Socket` to the `exchangeMessages()` method to be used, but this may not as convenient for the user of the method in the long term.

If your `Messenger` subclasses also have some specific behaviors (new methods / overridden implementations) not applicable to all types of `Messenger`, then Factory Method is certainly the way to go, as we need to subclass `Messenger` anyway and it allows us to strictly enforce the type of `Socket` created by the Factory Method `getSocket()`.

Perhaps others could contribute to the pros/cons of the Factory Method (specifically in Java as this the language tag for the question) and I can update this answer in due course.

---

**Validity of your example**

About whether your example is *invalid* or not. I think it helps to first fully understand the pattern and the important classes, operations and relationships in order to conform to the Factory Method pattern (as specified by the GoF).

The Factory Method Pattern allows you to define an *Operation* (or possibly several operations) in an abstract *Creator* class (in your case `Messenger`) which will use some Object (a *Product* [`Socket`]) without knowing the specific *Product* in advance and deferring its creation (hence the term **creational pattern**) to the *Factory Method*.

The *Factory Method* itself (`getSocket()`) is abstract in the *Creator* class and will be implemented by *Concrete Creators* (`TCPMessenger`, `UDPMessenger`) so polymorphism is used to achieve Object creation.

The *Factory Method* will return a *Concrete Product* (`TCPSocket`, `UDPSocket`) and have a return type applicable to all *Concrete Product* classes (`Socket`) used by the *Operation* in the abstract *Creator* class.

The *Operation(s)* (`exchangeMessages(String)`) that use the *Factory Method* will use the *Concrete Product* returned by the *Factory Method* by the interface *Product* which is applicable to all *Concrete Product* classes (`Socket`).

The result is that this pattern allows new *Concrete Product* classes to be added by implementing / subclassing the *Product* interface / class (or its subclasses...) and introducing a new *Concrete Creator* which returns the newly added *Concrete Product* from its *Factory Method*, preventing the need to re-write your *Operation(s)* that use this *Product*.

This means that we do not need to modify existing code when introducing new *Concrete Products* (Open/Closed Principle).

---

***Generalized UML for the Factory Method Pattern***

[image: Factory Method Pattern]

Some notes on the UML:

- The `factoryMethod()` can be given a default implementation in `Creator` (i.e. a default `Product` to return), in turn allowing `Creator` to be non-abstract
- The `factoryMethod()` could be `public` if desired, but this is superficial to the intention of the pattern since the `factoryMethod()` is primarily intended to be used by `operation()`
- `Product` does not have to be abstract class, it could be an interface or it could be a concrete class

---

**Validity of your example (continued)**

In reference to the UML (and your example), the important parts of the pattern in less wordy terms are as follows:

*There must exist*

- A `Product` interface (*not neccesarily an interface in Java terms, could be a class or abstract class in reality*) (in your case `Socket`)
- `ConcreteProduct` classes that implement the `Product` interface (`TCPSocket`, `UDPSocket`)
- An abstract `Creator` class (`Messenger`)
- A `Product factoryMethod()` method that is defined in the `Creator` class (`getSocket()`)

***Note***: The `Creator` *and* `factoryMethod()` *are usually abstract, but the* `Creator` *can define a default* `Product` *removing this requirement*.

- `operation()` methods in the `Creator` class that use the `ConcreteProduct` returned by the `factoryMethod()` (`exchangeMessages(String)`)
- At least one `ConcreteCreator` class (`TCPMessenger` and `UDPMessenger`))

*Such that*

- The `ConcreteCreator` classes implement the `Product factoryMethod()` to create and return a `ConcreteProduct`
- The abstract `Creator` class uses the `ConcreteProduct` (returned by `Product factoryMethod()`) through the interface for all `Product` implementations

The last two points reflect that `Creator` has a *use* dependency with the `Product` interface, and the `ConcreteCreator` classes have a *create* dependency with its corresponding `ConcreteProduct` class.

Again, note that the `Client` class is not part of the pattern itself (as defined by the GoF).

So in conclusion, your example would appear check out as the Factory Method in regards to the requirements listed above if the `TCPMessenger` and `UDPMessenger` class implement the `getSocket()` method correctly (which I assume they actually do).

Answer (score 4):

> for me, this is not a pattern but a core feature of Object-Oriented
>   Programming

Most of patterns rely on core OOP features : programming by interface, overriding, polymorphism, and so for...

> Moreover, I think that naming this creational is very confusing.
>   We actually care about exchangeMessages method, so Client (part of the
>   code that uses our "pattern") is not even aware of the Socket class
>   which creation we're all about. It's more like a way to implement
>   Messenger functionality (which can be easily extended etc...) than a
>   way to really create something.

It depends on the point of view you are taking.
For subclasses of the `Messenger` abstract class such as `TcpManager`, their parent class defines all but this factory method that they have to implement to specify what `Socket getSocket();` should return.
So for subclasses point of view, talking about a creational pattern for `Socket getSocket()` makes sense.

For client classes of `Messenger`, things are indeed different.
Clients may even not need to use directly this method.
For these classes, the important thing is indeed having a way to manipulate indifferently any subclass of `Messenger`.